# How to accept JSON post data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there a way I can simplify this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "create", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Response create(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) {
    return new Response(json.get("name").asText(), 200);
}
```

Mainly I wonder if it's possible to annotate consumes & produces. My app will be an API service so all requests/responses will be JSON based. I don't want to keep that over each controller method.

Less important:
I know I can pass `@RequestParam Comment comment` if this is a method to create a comment but what if I want to create a comment and something else at the same time from the same method.

Is there a cleaner way than doing ObjectNode and json and than `json.get().as...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out you can annotate your methods/controllers with `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestBody` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score -1):

MyServer.class

```
@POST
 public Response save(String data) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(repository.save(data)).build();
}
```

Now it will go to the server as post request.

if no id present, so add this code.

ResourceConverter converter = new ...
converter.disableDeserialisationOption(DeserializationFeature.REQUIRE_RESOURCE_ID);

This allows you to remove id restriction.
Alternative is that you should use current snapshot version

Here is the save method from the repository class

```
public String save(String data) {
    Server myServer= converter.readObject(data.getBytes(), Server.class);
    Key<Server> savedMyServer = datastore.save(myServer);
    Server usingKey = datastore.getByKey(Server.class, savedMyServer);

    try {
        return new String(converter.writeObject(usingKey), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```